# How to save a data after closing a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make some GUI on `Python3` with `tkinter`. So far I have *Main Window* and `'Test'` button on it, which opens *second window*. Second window has entry, label, save and close buttons. When you type something in entry and press `save` button, label shows the text you typed in entry. But after closing this window and opening it again, label shows nothing. How do I make this label to show the text that were typed last time before closing? For example, I type '`Hi`' in entry, press '`Save`', then I press '`Close`', then I open this window again and label shows '`Hi`'

```py
import tkinter as tk

def save_data(entry, t):
    t.config(text = entry.get())

def close_action(current_window):
    current_window.destroy()

def insertMainInfo():
    new_window = tk.Tk()
    new_window.geometry("307x131")
    new_window.title("TestWindow")

    test_entry = tk.Entry(new_window)
    test_entry.place(relx = 0.283, rely = 0.1, height = 24, width = 127)

    text = tk.Label(new_window)
    text.place(relx = 0.283, rely = 0.25, height = 24, width = 127)

    save_button = tk.Button(new_window, command = lambda: save_data(test_entry, text))
    save_button.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.45, height=24, width=127)
    save_button.configure(text = "Save")

    close = tk.Button(new_window, command = lambda: close_action(new_window))
    close.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.687, height=24, width=127)
    close.configure(text = "Close")

    new_window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    top = tk.Tk()
    top.geometry("307x131+557+330")
    top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    top.title("MainWindow")

    new_window_button = tk.Button(top, command = insertMainInfo)
    new_window_button.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.687, height=24, width=127)
    new_window_button.configure(text = "Test")

    main_label = tk.Label(top)
    main_label.place(relx=0.033, rely=0.153, height=41, width=284)
    main_label.configure(text = "TestLabel")

    top.mainloop()
```

Comment: In general saving data involves writing the data to your disk for later retrieval.  See [reading/writing file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: You can create a `StringVar` and pass it as a argument of `insertMainInfo()`. Then set the `textvariable` option to this variable for both label and entry.

Answer (score 1):

I have to confess that your question heading is a bit ambiguity.
If you just want to update a label of last entry, here a simple way of modifying your code.

As advised, as a good practice we only have one `Tk()` in a program, other new windows or pop-up windows should use `Toplevel()` of `tkinter` class; So I use this in your *`insertMainInfo()`* function.

The point here is to define a variable, I called *last_entry* and initially is empty or ‘’. Use this as parameter in *new_window* button in main program (after *`if __name__ == '__main__':`* ) to this variable (I also add lambda function here).

Then we define it as global in *`save_data`* function, so as it can be known later by other functions or main program as the last entry before *`new_window`* is closed.

Here I modify your code as said above, and I have tested it, and it works as expected.

```
import tkinter as tk

def save_data(entry, t):
    global last_entry
    last_entry = entry.get()
    t.config(text = last_entry)

def close_action(current_window):
    current_window.destroy()

def insertMainInfo(last_entry):
    new_window = tk.Toplevel()
    new_window.geometry("307x131")
    new_window.title("TestWindow")

    test_entry = tk.Entry(new_window)
    test_entry.place(relx = 0.283, rely = 0.1, height = 24, width = 127)

    text = tk.Label(new_window, text=last_entry)
    text.place(relx = 0.283, rely = 0.25, height = 24, width = 127)

    save_button = tk.Button(new_window, command = lambda: save_data(test_entry, text))
    save_button.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.45, height=24, width=127)
    save_button.configure(text = "Save")

    close = tk.Button(new_window, command = lambda: close_action(new_window))
    close.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.687, height=24, width=127)
    close.configure(text = "Close")

    new_window.mainloop()
    
# --- A Simple Data Structure ---
last_entry = ''


if __name__ == '__main__':

    top = tk.Tk()
    top.geometry("307x131+557+330")
    top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    top.title("MainWindow")

    new_window_button = tk.Button(top, command = lambda: insertMainInfo(last_entry))
    new_window_button.place(relx=0.283, rely=0.687, height=24, width=127)
    new_window_button.configure(text = "Test")

    main_label = tk.Label(top)
    main_label.place(relx=0.033, rely=0.153, height=41, width=284)
    main_label.configure(text = "TestLabel")
    
    top.mainloop()
```